# Taking Screenshot after 1 minute

Tags: c#, datetime, screenshot, timespan, stopwatch

I have two questions:

*1. How can I take screenshot after every 1 min, when a key is pressed E.g.*

> 1. 10:00: -> key pressed -> Img1
> 2. 10:01: -> key pressed -> Img2
> 3. 10:02: -> key pressed -> Img3

*2. How can I iterate the image chain assuming my program runs for 5-10 mins*

```
  string ImgPath = @"D:\"Img" + iteration + ".bmp";
  Bitmap btmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(btmp);
  g.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, btmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

> if (any key is pressed)
>   if (time difference is 1 min)
>   btmp.Save(ImgPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

Also if there is a more better way to take screenshot please share here.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried getting time difference between two consecutive key press.

Comment: @BhubanShrestha I am looking for a minute delay between next screenshot not two consecutive key presses.

Comment: @J.Doe didn't you want to find 1 minute difference while taking picture. If picture is taken 1 minute earlier then take another else not. Isn't your intention is like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is start (or restart) a [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) when you take a picture. Then, whenever a key is pressed, you check if the Stopwatch has been running for at least a minute. If it has, you take the picture and reset the stopwatch. The general idea:

```
// Start the clock when the program starts.
private Stopwatch _pictureTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// Wait this long between pictures
private readonly TimeSpan _pictureWaitTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);

// Come here when key is pressed.
if (_pictureTimer.Elapsed > _pictureWaitTime)
{
    // take the screen shot
    // and then reset the stopwatch
    _pictureTimer.Restart();
}
```

If you want to number the pictures, keep a variable that you update every time. When the program starts, you initialize it:

```
private int _pictureNumber = 1;
```

And whenever you take a picture, you increment it. That is, after resetting the stopwatch, just do:

```
_pictureNumber = pictureNumber + 1;
```